# Hub Page Header Template doesn't work as expected

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm porting over some Win RT code to UWP. One of the pages that doesn't work as expected is the HubPage.

I have a button in the `HubSection` `HeaderTemplate` which should be replacing the "see more" HyperLink. My button in my template appears but doesn't accept clicks.

The documentation states that I should be able to replace the "see more" hyperlink with my own template, I believe this is what my code is doing but doesn't work.

I'm unsure what value `IsHeaderInteractive` should be if I've attempting to replace the  `HubSection` `HeaderTemplate`. Any help apprecaited

```
<Page
    x:Class="Hub_Page.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Hub_Page"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="HubSection">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="This doesn't click!"
                                Background="DarkCyan" Tapped="UIElement_OnTapped"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid x:Name="outerGrid">
            <Grid x:Name="innerGrid"
              VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Hub x:Name="hub" SectionHeaderClick="Hub_OnSectionHeaderClick" >
                    <Hub.Header>
                        <!-- Back button and page title -->
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Margin="13,0,20,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button x:Name="backButton"  Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="x Manage Playlists" Margin="0,0,10,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <Button Content="This does click"
                                        Background="DarkGray" Tapped="UIElement_OnTapped"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Hub.Header>

                    <!-- Playlists section -->
                    <HubSection Header="x Playlists" IsHeaderInteractive="True" >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListView x:Name="playlistListView"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  SelectionMode="Single">
                                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <!-- A playlist -->
                                        <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxWidth="500">
                                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HubSection>
                </Hub>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's by design. You could make your own HubSection's button by yourself. For example like the following:

```
<HubSection>
     <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
               <Button Content="Header" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0 0 0 10"></Button>
               <TextBlock Text="here is content."></TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```